# How to convert a function to a string of its name in Swift

Tags: swift

`func displaySomething(something:UIView) {}` -> `"displaySomething"`

I am crazy about seletor type parameter in Swift. It just pass a string of the function name! I want to implement a function that pass in a function and give out a string, so I can use this function when I want pass a "selector type".

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd have a function to pass in without having the name already.

Comment: @NateCook This a request for the parallel to Objective-C's @selector(displaySomething:) which is useful because it participates in autocomplete, compile-time checking, and refactoring.

Comment: @JackLawrence OK, yeah, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Swift does not currently include runtime APIs to make this possible.

If you're interested in a feature to do this, you can file a feature request at http://bugreport.apple.com.